# Is there a solution to find central nodes in big graph beyond spark or mapreduce?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, networkx

Currently I am working big graph theory beyond mapreduce/spark.
The graph is too big to analysize, So I wanna remove some central nodes, making the big graph be splitted into several parts.
I tried NetworkX in python, it failed because the graph is too big.
Is there some solutions to realize it beyond spark or mapreduce?

Comment: I tried networkx.algorithms.distance_measures.center in Stand-alone, not works for big graph.

Comment: If you are trying to partition the graph see the [python-louvain package](https://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#community.best_partition)

Comment: Can this realized beyond spark or mapreduce?

Comment: I don't think so. You can however make "the big graph be splitted into several parts" using only networkX.

Comment: The big graph is a conencted graph having hundreds of millions of nodes, tens of billions of edges. I think NetWorkX only works in graph less than 100,000 nodes...